# What is the correct way to automatically include files on all pages of a website?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best and most effecient way to include a JavaScript file or stylesheet on every page of a website? For example, if I had a script that I included for analytics, I would want to have this script in every page of the website. I *could* just manually go through all my files and add it, but this could try tedious if I had a lot of files, and I might forget to add all the needed scripts when I created a new file.

Comment: This is too broad a question and depends on what technologies you're using. There are many different ways to do this.

Comment: Using plain html files instead to automatically generate them (by instance using php) causes this kind of troubles.  There are some command line tools that you could help you in this case, like `sed`, `find`, `awk` under linux, or others similars under other operating systems. Also some editors could help you to do it, like visual studio code or sublime using macros or other tools.  It depends of your working enviroment too.

Comment: You could add e.g. a script tag before sending the .html files to a client.
This can be done by some sort of middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use HTML and JS you won't get around doing it manually. You could write some .js file which loads the other styles and scripts you're intrested in to 'bundle' the imports into one file. However if you have any kind of backend you should setup some template that has the files included or a function that includes them.